# Force Regular Edit Mode (always) in Vim?

Tags: vim, text-editor

I like to work in Vim, but my colleagues don't. So, when I am discussing some source code with them, they may try to work on my computer, and of course, Vim is my default text editor. They get confused, have strange looks etc etc.

So, just for their benefit, **is there a way to force Vim to always be in Insert   mode** (off course temporarily)? So that they don't get confused and can use it like regular text editors (with few shortcuts, ctrl+c, ctrl+v...). I am aware that you can just work with Vim in Insert Mode. But occasionally, they may press `Escape`, and suddenly all hell breaks loose, as the cursor goes flying all over the place.

Hopefully, you will see my point. Or at-least sympathize with me...

Thanks of reading. (btw I am using GVim).

Comment: Why don't you just install the editor that your colleagues are used to, if they are going to use your machine that often?

Comment: I do have those installed. But all my source code defaults opens in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just do it for the current session , then you can just do `:set insertmode`. BTW , I dont think doing this is a good idea , but that is what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I set it temporarily for that session. I would never do it permanently in vimrc file. Is there a way to revert back while in the same session without restart?

Comment: @Cricrazy : You can press escape. :stopinsert is another option known.

Comment: As someone who isn't familiar with all the ins and outs of Vim, I ask, why don't you think it's a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

"evim", if you have that installed.  evim is basically "vim -y", which basically sets insertmode (and runs the GUI if available) upon startup and doesn't let you get out of that.

This is known as "Easy" Vim and is for people that just want to use it like most other editors out there.